# css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css"

Tags: stylesheet

I got this error while working with web app.
This is my master page

```xml
<head runat="server">
    <link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

This is the error:

```
Error: The stylesheet http://localhost:55381/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fStyles%2fSite.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".
Source File: http://localhost:55381/Login.aspx
Line: 0
```

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```xml
<location path="~/Styles">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
```

Where Styles is the folder that contains style sheet. I solved it this way

Answer (score 12):

Looks like your code is requiring a login to access the CSS stylesheet, and returning a HTML login page instead of the CSS.

To verify, try pasting the URL to the stylesheet into your browser, for instance http://localhost:55381/Styles/Site.css - if you get a login page instead of CSS, that's what you need to fix.

Comment: http://localhost:55381/Styles/Site.css  when i paste this URL it is redirecting to Login page as you said...so how to fix this ... i set login page as start page

Comment: It's your code; without seeing the code, absolutely no idea! :)

Answer (score 2):

@DavidPrecious gave a great answer that led me to the solution.

In my case, the **local computer's Users group** needed to be given **Read** permissions to the **c:\Inetpub** folder in order to allow the static content to be delivered properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is more likely an issue at your server side. You request style sheet page `Styles/Site.css` from the server of type `text/css`, but your server might be responding to this request with `test/html`. I had this issue when my server was running in Python and my server was replying to requested css files with header `text/html` (as that of my index.html file). I re-arranged my server code and assigned the correct headers to its corresponding pages and my issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: you've modified your .htaccess file to serve css as html.  Maybe something like this, for example:

```xml
<filesMatch "\.(htm|html|css|js)$">
ForceType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
</filesMatch>
```

You will want to remove the `css` from the first line if you've done this.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an nginx configuration problem, in the file where you declare the path to your static content.  I had to move `/etc/nginx/mime.types` out of the `http{}` block and further down into where I was serving the static content from.  It could similarly be an apache or IIS problem as well, depending on your technology stack.

```
location / {
   include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
   root                /path/to/static/content;
   try_files $uri /index.html = 404;
}
```